# What is a single pipe equivalent in dart?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I'm attempting to convert a piece of PHP code to dart and I came across a few things I've simply never used before, one of which is a single pipe `|`.  Im not sure what the exact dart equivalent is, if there even is one.

The piece of code in PHP I'm attempting to convert is:

```
$cc1 = (chr(ord($c1) / 64) | "\xc0");
```

What I've got so far converted into dart is:

```
var cc1 = (String.fromCharCode(c1.codeUnitAt(0) / 64) | "\xc0");
```

However, the single pipe `|` is giving me a dart error `The operator '|' isn't defined for the type 'String'.`, but as far as I can tell, the php `chr` should be giving a string as its output, so it brings up the question of if single pipe is actually doing the same thing in dart as it does in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation is bitwise-OR, and the equivalent operator is `|`.  However, PHP is lenient about types, and Dart is type-safe.  It will not convert strings to integers for you.  You can do:

```dart
var cc1 = c1.codeUnitAt(0) | 0xc0;
```

`cc1` will be an `int`.  If, say, you want it to be a `String` with the hexadecimal representation, you can do:

```dart
var cc1 = (c1.codeUnitAt(0) | 0xc0).toRadixString(16);
```

Comment: I was about to give a similar reply: you beat me to it.  You're absolutely correct: "|" is just a "bitwise OR" (exactly the same as in C, C++, Java, C# ... and Dart).  The difference is that PHP  (as you put it) is "lenient about types"... so PHP allows you to treat the string `"\xc0"` as the binary value `0xc0`.  Dart, of course, doesn't.